# Sliding Window Algorithm (Finding max consecutive numbers that add up to a specific sum)

Tags: java, queue, sliding-window

```
public class Main {
    static final int k = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {1, -1, -3, 3, 7, -7, -1, -1, 10, 2};

        int startIndex = 0, endIndex = 0, currentSum = 0;
        int maxDigitsUsed = Integer.MIN_VALUE;


        while(endIndex < arr.length - 1){
            currentSum += arr[endIndex];
            if (currentSum == k && maxDigitsUsed < endIndex - startIndex) {
                maxDigitsUsed = endIndex - startIndex;
            } else {
                endIndex++;
            }
        }


        // moving the startIndex forward when there is a chance to change the sum to k
        while (startIndex <= endIndex) {
            currentSum -= arr[startIndex];
            if (currentSum == k && maxDigitsUsed < endIndex - startIndex) {
                maxDigitsUsed = endIndex - startIndex;

            }
            startIndex++;

        }
 }
```

My professor went through a simple sliding window algorithm which checks for the maximum consecutive digits that add up to a specified sum k, in this case k = 0.

**However, it does not seem to work when negative numbers are present. Why is this so and how should I rectify it? Also, the original implementation was supposed be a queue so any queue based answers would be very helpful!**

This array based implementation was solely MY ATTEMPT, so please forgive any egregious errors. The original question involved only positive integers and used a queue instead of an array.

Comment: Instead of using a sliding window. You need to use a prefix sum array in case there are neg numbers present

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked *too* deeply at this, but I can tell that your code won't do what you want it to.  The way you're doing the sliding window can't actually find all possible combinations of consecutive digits.

What it looks like your code is doing is sliding the end index forward until you either reach the desired sum, or hit the end of the array.  Then you slide the start index forward with those same restrictions.  So what you end up with is a window that does this:

```
[o - - - -]
[o o - - -]
[o - o - -]
[o - - o -]
[o - - - o]
[- o - - o]
[- - o - o]
[- - - o o]
[- - - - o]
```

Note that at no point will your window ever look like this:

```
[- o - o -]
```

So if that happens to be the largest window that adds up to the desired sum, your algorithm will never find it.  So you need to work on getting your code to hit all possible windows.  The most obvious way to do that is with a nested loop.  You can slide your end index all the way to the end, and then bump your start index up by one, reset your sum, and slide your end index from that new starting point to the end again.  Repeat this for all possible start indices, and that should cover every single window on the array.

Comment: I am guessing this is an O(n^2) approach? Is there some way of using a queue to help making it O(n)? Because the original question with all positive integers could be solved using a queue in O(n) time.